# Gnome (Wayland) multiple dpi almost correct

Tags: gnome3, multi-monitor, wayland

I have setup gnome on a 2 screen system: 1) a primary 4K display scaled 200% and 2) a secondary 1080p display at normal scaling. After some configuration I have gotten everything scaled perfectly on the primary screen (both GTK and Qt applications) and *almost* everything on the secondary screen.

The 2 issues that remain are:

- Title bars on the 1080p screen are large, **only** in Qt or gtk2 programs
- Cursor size on the 1080p screen is large **only** in Qt or gtk2 programs

The Qt tile bar scaling may be seen here:

[image]

The system was configured for scaling by setting the scaling on the primary display to 200% via the display settings in the control panel. The Qt application scaling was done by setting some variables in `/etc/.profile`. The relevant contents of this file is as follows:

```
export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=2
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2
```

Does anyone have suggestions to potentially fix this issue?

Comment: I don't have any insight as to your issue, but I'm working on something exactly the same. I'm trying to get per-monitor scaling to work properly. However, GNOME defaults to X11 on my Fedora 30 system. Can you explain how you got your system to default to Wayland? Or some links perhaps? Seems everything I find is about leaving Wayland for X11...